# Lock holds thread without acquiring the lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

and 2 methods

```
public void m1(){
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("m1");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
}

public void m2(){
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("m2");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
}
```

I want only method m2 to held the lock and m1 to just check if the lock is held then wait until is unlocked and execute the code, but I don't want m1 to acquire any lock.

For example:

```
T1 -> m1 // no lock acquired
T2 -> m1 // no lock acquired
T3 -> m2 // lock acquired
T4 -> m1 // wait until T3 finish executing m2 then execute m1
```

Comment: Why do you want it ? Consider spinning in m1 while (lock.isLocked()) { }. Most likely there is something wrong with your design. Also you can use ReadWriteLock, read lock on m1 and write lock on m2

Comment: Consider using a CountDownLatch - all threads wanting to invoke m1() wait until some thread invokes m2().

Comment: @Anton I only want m2 to block threads executing either m1 or m2 until m2 is executed. if no thread is executing m2 I don't want to apply any lock mechanism to m1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use a `Condition` and wait on a boolean till the condition is true

```
Condition methodM2finished= lock.newCondition();
boolean m2done=false;
```

in method m1

```
public void m1(){
        lock.lock();
        try {
         while(!m2done){//wait till this flag becomes true
           try{
                methodM2finished.await();
              }
           catch(InterruptedException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
            System.out.println("m1");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
}
```

And in m2

```
public void m2(){
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("m2");
            //after all the business logic is done
           m2done=true;
           methodM2finished.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
}
```

Comment: tryLock also acquires the lock

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder the statements:

```
public void m1(){
  lock.lock(); 
  // No need for finally, no statement to complete abnormally.
  lock.unlock();

  System.out.println("m1");
}
```

Sure, this will acquire the lock; but it immediately releases it again; so the lock isn't held while the statement is printed.